# Recieving SystemError: NULL result without error in PyObject_Call when using Python multiprocessing

Tags: python, image-processing, multiprocessing, threadpool, anaconda

I have searched around and there have been several questions on this issue, but none of them seem to fit my context.

I am working on an algorithm for image segmentation in Python, using the anaconda distribution. In the beginning stages of the algorithm, a weight matrix must be calculated, to give the weights of the edges between every pixel of an image (using the pixels as nodes in a weighted graph data structure). Obviously, this results in a matrix of a huge size, `((imageWidth * imageHeight)**2)`. This takes a very long time to build for larger and larger images, so a while back I implemented a couple of functions to build the matrix using all cpu's on the machine.

This has worked perfectly fine for me for weeks during testing. However, our algorithm has been steadily improving, and it is now ready to test on some real data (gathered from an x-ray microscope). Our tests have so far been no larger than 64x64, and that took quite a while, so we have moved to a machine with 40 processors.

Now that we have moved, I all of the sudden am getting an error at the multiprocessing function:

`SystemError: NULL result without error in PyObject_Call`

I don't understand this, because the only difference is the number of cpu's. Why should that cause an issue? If someone knows more about how python's multiprocessing package actually works, then maybe you can see something that I don't.

Here are the functions in question. The first initiates the process pool:

```
def CreateMatrix(self, sigmaI, sigmaX):                                

    cpus = mp.cpu_count()
    poolCount = cpus
    args = [(self, sigmaI, sigmaX, i,) for i in range(self.numPixels)]

    pool = mp.Pool(processes = poolCount)
    tempData = pool.map(unwrap_CreateMatrix, args)

    for pixelList in tempData:                                          
        for pixel in pixelList:
            self.data[pixel[1]] = pixel[0]

    self.matrix = numpy.matrix(self.data.reshape(self.columns, self.rows), numpy.float64)
    return
```

The second one if called by each process (and has nothing to dow ith the creation or handling of the process pool, so I doubt the issue is here):

```
def CreateMatrixPixelA(self, sigmaI=1, sigmaX=1, i = 0):               

    pixelA = self.pixelArray[i]
    pixelAData = []

    j = 0
    for pixelB in self.pixelArray:
        stride = (i * self.numPixels) + j

        locationDiff = self.CalcLocationVectorNorm(pixelA, pixelB)

        if locationDiff < self.distance:
            intensityDiff = self.CalcPixelVectorNorm(pixelA, pixelB)   
            locationDiff = -1 * pow(locationDiff,2)
            intensityDiff = -1 * pow(intensityDiff, 2)                 
            value = math.exp(intensityDiff / sigmaI) * math.exp(locationDiff / sigmaX)
            pixelAData.append((value, stride))

        j += 1

    return pixelAData
```

Also this one, just to spare any confusion:

```
def unwrap_CreateMatrix(args):                                                
    return WeightMatrix.CreateMatrixPixelA(*args)
```

Sorry for the big wall of text. I'm sure the answer to this is quite simple, I just don't know what kind of information will help, so I have included everything relevant. My only thoughts are that the image I'm using is too big (highly doubt, though), or there may be an issue with the packages installed on this machine (though this machine is using anaconda just as all other testing machines were.)

Comment: How big are the images you are processing now? Can you evaluate ((imageWidth * imageHeight)**2) for me?

Comment: The image that I have been trying to use now on these bigger tests is exactly `209x209` pixels. So that creates `43,681` individual processes (but only 40 at one time, maximum, I would assume?). So there are `1,908,029,761` total matrix entries, though not nearly that many actual calculations, since the majority are set to zero (due to the if statement in `CreateMatrixPixelA`; `if locationDiff < self.distance`, where `self.distance` is the maximum distance two pixels can be apart to even have a nonzero weight between them.)

Comment: So you are creating a process per pixel. What line is the code failing at? Have you tried steadily increasing the area of the image you are processing from 64x64 upwards, to see if it fails at a particular point?

Comment: It is failing in the multiprocess module, here:

`File "/anaconda/x86_64/lib/python2.7/multiprocessing/pool.py", line 251, in map
    return self.map_async(func, iterable, chunksize).get()
  File "/anaconda/x86_64/lib/python2.7/multiprocessing/pool.py", line 567, in get
    raise self._value`
 
The strange thing is that it gets to creating around 30 of the processes before I'm given an error. And yes, I can do that.

Comment: Does it work on your original 64x64 test image on this new machine? That would have 4096 tasks to run. it certainly sounds like something is running out of memory - the return values are each 43k values, how many bytes is that? Also your approach has to collect every single result before any of them are used and then can be discarded to free memory. Have you tried using map_async so when each pixel has been processed the callback function can use the data then free it up?

Comment: I guess each entry in the args list contains the full source image, because self is included. Your args list is then 44k*(44k pixel values + other stuff). How much memory is this, in bytes? You may want to consider reserving one of the CPUs just for the controlling script. One simple way of reducing the memory needs would be to chunk the pixel processing into a few (16? 32?) smaller 'runlets'?

Comment: @barny it is working for a 120x120 image. I don't want to continue cropping images and testing, since each test takes a while, but it is between 120 pixels and 200 pixels that it fails. Either way, this is not a very big image, so not desirable. You're right that it seems something is running out of memory. But when I use a 400x400 image, I get a memory error instantly, before the mulritprocessing even starts. It is strange to me that with sufficiently small images, I get no errors. With very big images I get memory errors, but with in-between-sized images, I get no memory errors and a crash.

Comment: @barny No, the source image is not included in the args list, that is not needed. In fact, I don't think that `self` should be included in args, and am not sure why it is, as `CreateMatrix` and `CreateMatrixPixelA` are in the same class. Thanks for catching that, I will see if it makes a difference to remove.

Comment: Nevermind, `self` was neccessary because of the `unwrap` function being outside of the class.

Comment: @jphollowed: I don't think it's strange that you receive different errors for different image sizes. It just means that your program is running out of memory during different stages. From what I can tell, the `self.data` array has size `numpixels**2` and consequently takes a lot of RAM. Is it really necessary to keep this array around or can you maybe take the sum (or any other reduction) in between?

Comment: Also, it *could* be possible to do this operation entirely with Numpy vectorized methods, resulting in speedups of maybe 100x. That would mean you may not need to bother with multiprocessing at all.